# How create raw of rtp audio?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, hex, rtp

I have one packet rtp, this packet have payload and payload is (PAYLOAD FILE):
[image]

I get raw file for this payload with Audacity and result is (RAW FILE):
[image]

How does convert **fe** to **00 00 80 39** ?
I will do with python ?
How arrange raw file for create stereo ?

I will create stereo wav file of rtp.
My file is float 32.

Exp 2:
Payload:
[image]

RAW(Audacity):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

RTP payload will have separate channel payload for each Audio channel ( Audio payload e.g. - LLLL...RRRR.. as per rfc specification.

Stereo Audio data is interleaved with - LR LR LR - data ( L- Left R - Right channel Audio data)

Write code that will convert the Mono byte array(payload) to stereo data.

you can chose any programming language of your choice.